# The best approach of getting changes of all input fields in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

I would like to create a confirmation for handling changes of a page. For example `gmail` or other plenty of other websites has a system that when you change a field in the page and when you would like to leave page or clear the form inputs , the site will create a confirmation dialogue which help you to save the changes that you have forgotten. Here is my solution but I wonder whether there is a better way or not. Also the project is JSF project and using primefaces 3.4
**Solution:**
1.Create a global js variable

> ```
> var isChanges = false;
> ```

1. Put the handler on all input fields onchanges method.

> < p:inputText value="#{someMB.someValue}" id="id" onkeydown="isChanges=true">< /p:inputText>
>   or 
>       < p:selectOneMenu value="#{someMB.someValue}" id="#{cc.attrs.id}" >
>               < p:ajax event="change" onsuccess="isChanges=true" />
>       < /p:selectOneMenu>
>   etc....

Detect whether user leave page or clear form inputs:

```
< script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
      if(isChanged && window.confirm("sometext")){
        // Call servers save method
      }
  }

< /script>
```

Comment: This is not a JSF question but generic web application.

Comment: I just wonder maybe primefaces or other jsf frameworks can handle this.

Comment: You're confusing concepts. The requests are handled by the web server (JSF, PrimeFaces, Struts2, Spring, ASP.NET MVC, PHP, etc) and the client operations (like leaving out a tab) are handled by the client (HTML, Javascript, CSS).

Comment: OK, sorry for missunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my web application, I do this:

1. when the page loads, grab all form, except those with a special `noHash` class
2. for each form found at above step, grab all fields except those with a special `noHash` class
3. serialize fields names and values in a string like "var1=1&var2=2[...]"
4. compute sha1 of string as defined above
5. store the result as a global variable

Then, when a user tries to navigate away, I recompute the hash as described above and see if the hashes are different, if they are I prompt the user for confirmation before leaving the page.

Please note that this is **all** done using javascript, so is independent of your server side script language.